# Why is it possible to change values of a final object?

Tags: java, class, object, final, setter

I have a Java Class Point. To gain quick access to the point (0, 0), I provide a constant for it.

```
public class Point{
    //...
    public static final Point NULLPOINT=new Point(0, 0);
    //...
}
```

However this Point.NULLPOINT.setX(x) still works and changes the NULLPOINT to (x, 0). Is there a way to prevent this? I thought final would to prevent this, but apparently I overestimated its power.

Comment: Your not changing the object reference, but its internal properties

Comment: The "final" tag means that variable NULLPOINT cannot be reset to point to another Point, not that the existing NULLPOINT's content can't be changed.

Answer (score 3):

`final` guarantees the reference will not change, i.e. you will not be able to reassign another `Point` object to `NULLPOINT` reference. But still you may change the object state. If you need to ensure `NULLPOINT` state will not change you should make `Point` class immutable: remove setters for example.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you said that the `reference` is final, not the contents at that reference.

Answer (score 0):

Because all object variables in Java are references to objects, making NULLPOINT final means that no one can change which Point NULLPOINT refers to. The java.awt.Point class is mutable, but there are some things you can do to accomplish a similar effect.

First, you could declare NULL_X and NULL_Y values, and compare the x and y values of any other Point to those. Second, you could implement an ImmutablePoint class with all the methods you need for NULLPOINT that has no setters. Third, you could write a nullpoint() function that returns a new Point at (0,0).

All of those options have their upsides and downsides in terms of performance and ease of use.

Comment: The ImmutablePoint sultion seems fine, is there away to let in inhere from Point and disabling all the setter without empty overriding them (a way to exclude them from the will if you know what I am trying to say)?

Comment: I believe that empty-overriding them is the only way to do it, and that is an ugly solution. Also, Point's x and y fields are public, so even without those methods they could be changed.